# Initialize not null jagged array

Tags: c#, jagged-arrays, non-nullable, spec#

I am currently studying computing at UCLAN and I have to write a program using Spec# and I need a 2 dimensial jagged array which can not be null. 
I know for a normal array I can declare it like this

```
T![]!
```

but when i want to declare it for a jagged array I should write it somehow like this

```
T![]![]
```

This works pretty well but when I want to init it:

```
T![]![] = new T![365]![]
```

it throws an error and I just can't find how to get this fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I did not find out how I can init the array correctly but I found a workaround.

```
T![]![]! = (T![]![]) new T![][];
```

This is how it works!